# Passing the parameters in command Pattern java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a class and method which has main functionality in that.

```
public class SeriesOfCommand {
    List<Products> listofproducts = ListOfProducts.retrieveProducts();

    public List<Products> filterByPrice(float min,float max){           
        if(listofproducts!=null){
            System.out.println(listofproducts.size() +" size: " +listofproducts);
            List<Products> filteredListOfProducts = listofproducts.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getPrice() >= min && p.getPrice() <= max)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(filteredListOfProducts.toString());
            return filteredListOfProducts;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So here I want to use COMMAND PATTERN while calling that method using execute 
but I am facing problem how do I pass these parameter here for method `weightFilter.filterByWeight(min, max)`. I have a servlet which read the user inputs from jsp

```
public class WeightFilter implements ICommmand {
    SeriesOfCommand weightFilter;

    public WeightFilter(SeriesOfCommand weightFilter) {
        this.weightFilter = weightFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void filterBy() {
        //here how do I give min and max values to the method as am reading the user inputs from servlet ans jsp
        weightFilter.filterByWeight(min, max);
    }
}
```

Servlet where the getting the parameter and setting it as attribute

```
    String minWeight = request.getParameter("minWeight");
    String maxWeight = request.getParameter("maxWeight");
    float min = Float.parseFloat(minWeight);
    float max = Float.parseFloat(maxWeight);

    request.setAttribute("minWeight", minWeight);
    request.setAttribute("maxWeight", maxWeight);
    request.setAttribute("filterByWeight", weightFilter.filterBy(min, max));
```

Calling the method ..
Then the attribute am setting for min and max  and just printing those results given by method in the JSP

Comment: Maybe you should post relevant parts of your jsp and/or servlet

Comment: I have provided the servlet part... helps will be appreciated, Thanks